# UIWebView in UIScrollView Zooming without loosing resolution

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a simple UIWebView in a UIScrollView for the sake of zoom capability.
The HTML inside UIWebView is displayed fine, unless I start zooming in, when it gets fuzzy. Now, the web page is basically text. But UIScrollView handles the whole UIWebView a static image, apparently, and so, by getting bigger, it loses its clarity and resolution.

I have seen some posts, saying that there is no solution for it, but I still doubt it. Safari can do it. So, there should be a way.

Any help? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the UIWebView in a UIScrollView. It handles zooming automatically. Just set the `scalesPageToFit` property on the web view to YES.

Comment: I did... didn't work. what am I missing? ... [self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

Comment: What web page are you visiting? Some sites have a special <meta> tag that prevents scaling... Try a page that's not mobile-optimised?

Comment: Thanks. it worked. the problem was, as you said, mobile optimized webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Remove uiscrollview and simply take uiwebview in xib and mark on scale page to fit and set the delegat of uiwebview. It handles zooming automatically.